Define DWORD constant with characters
In C++, is it valid to define DWORD constant with characters? like below:
const DWORD WAVE_FORMAT = 'WAVE'; // Equivalent to 0x45564157

I have never done so in the past, but the above code can be compiled without problems. I am using Visual C++ 2008

'WAVE' is an example of a multicharacter literal. They exist in C++, but their meaning is implementation defined. So 'WAVE' might be equivalent to 0x45564157 on your compiler, but on a different compiler it might mean something else, or not be legal at all.

Visual C++ 2008 ???
